# What does "RGB Stripe" mean, in relation to the Nokia Lumias

Tags: lumia, display

I was [comparing the  features of some Lumias](http://www.nokia.com/gb-en/products/compare/?action=productcompareaction&site=64060&products=1808274-1811462-233018&operation=show) and one of the display "features" for the Lumia 920 and 820 is "RGB Stripe" - what makes this so special (say, in comparison to the 800 that doesn't list it as a feature)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It refers to the pixel layout on the screen. On a RGB stripe display the red, green and blue pixels are the same size and have the same count. In comparison, a [PenTile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PenTile) RGBG uses a smaller green pixel (since the human eye is most sensitive to green), so the screen ends up having less pixels than a RGB strip display of the same resolution and is therefore cheaper.

The RGB Stripe layout gives better colours and a sharper image when compared to something like a PenTile layout. Some fonts look very jagged on a PenTile layout but look very crisp on a RGB strip layout--I also find them to have a strange green hue.

The Lumia 800 has a PenTile display but due to the small screen size it isn't as noticeable. The larger 900 has a RGB stripe.

You can clearly see the difference between PenTile layout (left) and RGB stripe (right) in the below image.

[image: Pentile vs RGB]

More examples can be found [here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-hardware/167679-slcd-samoled-pentile-rgb-does-matter.html#post1711760) (disclaimer: Android site) and a full explanation on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering).